# Change variable value color with bootstrap/javascript in jinja2 templating

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2, bootstrap-4

I have a requirement where I have to display different color to (Open, In Progress, Reopened, Resolved, Closed.) Jira status. The below works for now

```
{% set state = 'Closed' %}
{% if state =='Open' %}
    <p class="text-primary">{{ state }}</p>
{% elif state =='Closed' %}
    <p class="text-danger">{{state }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Is there any other way than above. I heard bootstrap can do this? 
If I use above code I have to write it atleast 20 times in my code. So I need a script I can use in HTML where I do status('state') and it should work like magic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Bootstrap for the CSS.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/

And you *could* utilise JavaScript for rendering the HTML.

```
<script>

function setState(state) {
    let setClass;
    switch(state) {
        case 'Open':
            setClass = 'text-primary'
        break;
        case 'Closed':
            setClass = 'text-danger'
        break;
        default:
            setClass = 'text-dark'
    }
    return '<p class="'+setClass+'">'+state+'</p>';
}

// Usage:
setState('Open')

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work for me. It prints setState('Open') when I try this

Comment: Make sure you're using `<script>` open and `</script>` close tags around JavaScript always. I will edit the answer to reflect usage.

Comment: Does setState('open') have to be inside script tag? I was using in my div's directly.